# How to get value from object in C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a simple ATM program in C# and it is suppose to be Object Oriented.
I created a public class ATM and inside it a another public class ACC (account).
How can i create method inside ATM class to write how much money is in ATM.ACC.ACCSaldo?

```
public class ACC
{
    public int ACCNr;       //accaunt number
    public int ACCPIN;      //PIN number
    public double ACCSaldo; //How much money is in account

    //constr
    public ACC(int p, int p2, double p3)
    {
        ACCNr = p;
        ACCPIN = p2;
        ACCSaldo = p3;
    }
}
```

My main part of code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ATM ATM01 = new ATM();

    ATM.ACC acc1 = new ATM.ACC(3333, 1234, 3000.53);

    acc1.ACCNr = ATM01.czytnik();

    Console.WriteLine("ACCNr: {0}", acc1.ACCNr);
    Console.WriteLine("PIN: {0}", acc1.ACCPIN);
    Console.WriteLine("Saldo: {0}", acc1.ACCSaldo);

    ATM.tstPIN tstPIN1 = new ATM.tstPIN(acc1.ACCNr, acc1.ACCPIN ,acc1.ACCSaldo);
    tstPIN1.test();

    ATM.menu();

    // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What about your existing code is not working? `acc1.ACCSaldo` should work fine; are you seeing an error?

Comment: That would be fine in main part of program after creating acc1.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to access `acc1` in a *different* method to the one you've already got?

Comment: What I'm after is a method that is inside ATM class and can be used in main program. Something like:
     public static void writeSaldo()
            {
                double x;
                x = ACC.ACCSaldo;
                Console.WriteLine("You got {0} dolars.", x);
            }


And then in main part I should write something like:
ATM.writeSaldo();

Comment: I know you did not ask this, but you should use `decimal` for monetary amounts, not `double`.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one Account in the ATM, you can declare a ACC instance (e.g. _acc) in the ATM; You need to initialise in your main method, then you can do sth like:

```
public void DisplayAccountDetails()
{
   Console.Write(String.Format("Account Balance:{0}", _acc.ACCSaldo));
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could add get and set properties. 
    public double ACCSaldo{
        get;
        set;
    }

Comment: Sorry to say this but I don't know what get; set; is and how to use it.

Comment: Instead of just declaring the variable in your class for example: public double ACCSaldo;  , what you can do is in the declaration give it get and set properties, do this by putting {get; set;} after it. The get allows another class to get the value, while the set allows you to set the value. If you need any other explanation there are many tutorials on the internet just search get and set properties. This should definitely fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one account in the ATM class and it looks similar to the follow:

```
public class ATM
{
    public ACC Acc;
}
```

You can add a method inside the ATM class like the following:

```
public void WriteSaldo()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Saldo: {0}", Acc.ACCSaldo);
}
```

Then in your `Main` method you can use `ATM01.WriteSaldo();`